# How to export HTML to PDF with ASP.net mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a report develop with asp.net mvc4 using HTML and I want to export this report to PDF file with asp.net MVC4 anybody help me please?  thank!

Answer (score 6):

Use Razor PDF for generating PDF Reports. Here goes simple process.

Step 1 - Create MVC application

Step 2 - Install Rotativa PDF Nuget.

Step 3 - Place a simple model like this

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Step 4 - Create a simple view for the model we created above, name the view as Index.

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Controllers.Person>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Age)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Step 5 - Create a simple controller action.

> ```
>     public ActionResult IndexNew()
>     {
>         return new ActionAsPdf("GeneratePDF");
>     }
>
>     public ActionResult GeneratePDF()
>     {
>         List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
>         persons.Add(new Person() { Age = "29", Name = "Rami1" });
>         persons.Add(new Person() { Age = "28", Name = "Rami2" });
>         return View("Index", persons);
>     }
> ```

Run the application and navigate to IndexNew Controller Action, a PDF will be generated out of GeneratePDF() Action and will be downloaded by the browser as shown below -

[image]

Comment: At the top, you say you are using RazorPDF, and also a bit later say you are using Rotativa, are you really using both in this example?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this application:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/260470/PDF-reporting-using-ASP-NET-MVC

and if you want to download the file directly you can do it with a FileContentResult:

```
protected FileContentResult ViewPdf(string pageTitle, string viewName, object model)
{
string htmlText = this.htmlViewRenderer.RenderViewToString(this, viewName, model);
byte[] buffer = standardPdfRenderer.Render(htmlText, pageTitle);
return File(buffer, "application/pdf","file.pdf");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the report is another view in the same application you can use the following C# to get the HTML string of that view and then convert the HTML string to PDF to produce a PDF in a buffer that can be saved on server or sent to a browser for download. The code is using [evo html to pdf converter for .net](http://www.evopdf.com/)  to convert the HTML string to PDF. The advantage of this approach is that the session data is available in report view during conversion:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ConvertPageInSameSessionToPdf(FormCollection collection)
{
    object model = null;
    ViewDataDictionary viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model);

    // The string writer where to render the HTML code of the view
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

    // Render the Index view in a HTML string
    ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, "Report_View", null);
    ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(
            ControllerContext,
            viewResult.View,
            viewData,
            new TempDataDictionary(),
            stringWriter
            );
    viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, stringWriter);

    // Get the view HTML string
    string htmlToConvert = stringWriter.ToString();

    // Get the base URL
    String currentPageUrl = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    String baseUrl = currentPageUrl.Substring(0, currentPageUrl.Length - "Report_View".Length);

    // Convert the HTML string to a PDF document in a memory buffer
    byte[] outPdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertHtml(htmlToConvert, baseUrl);

    // Send the PDF file to browser
    FileResult fileResult = new FileContentResult(outPdfBuffer, "application/pdf");
    fileResult.FileDownloadName = "Report.pdf";

    return fileResult;
}
```